# How to force Spring-Boot application to use default logging configurations

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, log4j, logback

### Regarding this issue in IDEA in business project

The project I am working on demands to have a different logging-configuration: has no colors and is formatted horribly.

Due to many different circumstances, we are not able to change the setup of the project oder even the <kbd>PatternLayout</kbd> of the file. Additionally, I want to avoid changing the file for my local tests and accidentally end up committing the changes. We are using Intellij as our IDE of choice.

Sadly, I am not allowed to share the actual structure but will try my best to outline the issue:

Simplified project tree:

```
 my-simple-project
    |-- pom.xml
    |-- src
    |   |-- main
    |   |   |-- java
    |   |   `-- resources
    |   |       `-- bootstrap.yml
    |   `-- test
    |       |-- java
    |       `-- resources
    |           |-- application.yml
    |           `-- log4j2.xml
    `-- target (after using maven)
```

Starting <kbd>my-simple-project</kbd> through a <kbd>Spring Boot-runConfiguration</kbd>, it automatically uses the <kbd>log4j2.xml</kbd> from the <kbd>src/test/resources</kbd> directory as its logging-configuration.

There **is no declaration to use the xml-file** in either the Module-settings of IDEA, the pom.xml or the runConfiguration.

The **log-output (debug-output is enabled) has no information about it either**.

If I remove the xml-file from my <kbd>src/test/resources</kbd> it auto-magically goes back to the default-configurations.

**The question is whether there is a system-property, environment variable or something else that allows me to force Spring-Boot to use the default logging-configuration?**

---

### When executing the application as a jar

The log-configuation can be changed even when bundled into a jar. Here I am passing [<kbd>logging.config</kbd> as a property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html#:%7E:text=but%20you%20can%20set%20the%20location%20of%20the%20config%20file%20using%20the%20%22logging.config%22%20property.) (<kbd>-Dlogging.config=/path/to/log4j2.xml</kbd>). This though is not an issue, since I can simply remove the property and it goes back using the default configurations. Leaving it empty makes Spring-Boot think I want to use nothing and therefore logs nothing.

The problem lies when the xml-file is packaged into the jar and explicity referenced through the <kbd>application.yml/application.properties</kbd> or through the **classpath**. Now, I am unable to remove the logging-configuration for test/examination purposes.

It would be nice, if there was a way to tell Spring-Boot to go back to the default-configuration.

---

I did read through the [Logging-documentations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.3.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging) described by the spring-team. But as far I understood, it describes how I am able define a different logging-configuration or extend on currently existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

After being able to update IntelliJ to the newest version (from Version 2022.x to 2023.x), it seems that the reference to `src/test/resources` was added into the runConfiguration.